# How to set up the path to my custom Gas3 template?

Tags: apache-flex, graniteds

Gas3 is not able to find my custom template.

I replaced the default path:

```
class:org/granite/generator/template/remoteBase.gsp
```

With my file, like this:

```
class:myPackage/remoteBase.gsp
```

But every time Gas3 tries to create the .as of my classes I get a Resource not Found exception.
I tried different paths but all gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the path to the custom template has to be declared differently.

Like this:

```
file:///myPackage/remoteBase.gsp
```